# How can I initialize the sandbox of my iOS app during installation?

Tags: ios

I was trying to put some files into the apps' sandbox before the users first run of this app. Right now I can only do this by copying the files from the supporting files to the sandbox during the first run.

Is there a better way to do this? Can this be done during the installation of the app rather  than the first run?

Comment: NO you can't. You have to do it once the user runs the app for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, iOS does not have any kind of install system you can hook into.

You can only run code on first run, which is a good way to do it. Just don't set a flag in the `NSUserDefaults` the you have don the copying, but rather check whether the needed files are document or cache directory. Since restoring a backup can sometimes, depending on the flag, skip files. and not the `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the copying on

*- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions* Inside AppDelegate.m file.